# Create function to return an updated path in BASH

Tags: bash

I have a function in bash to remove the first two directories of a path. This works fine. I would like to add to it the ability to append a new starting path, and I'm having issues. Here is what I have so far:

```
function fp {
  echo $1 | cut -d'/' -f4-
}
```

If I call the function like so:

```
fp 'dir1/dir2/dir3/file'
```

It returns 'dir3/file1'.  I now need it to return 'dir5/dir6/dir3/file', how do I append the additional directories in front of the path?

UPDATE:

The original purpose of the method was to create an alias that would copy updated files in to a git repo if they had changed. Here is the full code that now works:

```
# Update dotfiles if there are any changes                                                                                                                         
alias dotu='for file in $(diff -qr ./ ~/ | grep differ | cut -d " " -f; do eval $(fp "$file"); echo "$file"; done'                                                                                                                                                                                                              
function fp {                                                                                                                                                      
  printf "%s%s" "cp $1 ~/dotfiles/" $(echo $1 | cut -d'/' -f4-)                                                                                                    
}
```

Being not so good at bash, this may be ugly but it works for me.

UPDATE #2:

Ok, here's what I ended up with, having the function do the copy itself:

```
# Update dotfiles if there are any changes                                                                                                                         
alias dotu='for file in $(diff -qr ./ ~/ | grep differ | cut -d " " -f; do fp "$file"; echo "$file"; done'                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
function fp {                                                                                                                                                      
  cp $1 ~/dotfiles/${1#*/*/*/}                                                                                                                                     
}
```

UPDATE #3:

One more time, hopefully this is now good.

```
# Update dotfiles if there are any changes                                                                                                                         
alias dotu='for file in $(diff -qr ./ ~/ | grep differ | cut -d " " -f; do fp "$file"; echo "$file"; done'                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
function fp {                                                                                                                                                      
  cp "$1" ~/dotfiles/"${1#*/*/*/}"                                                                                                                                     
}
```

Comment: Is the new starting path constant, or should it be passed as a parameter?

Comment: `dir5/dir6/dir3/file`? Where are `dir5` or `dir6` coming from?

Comment: It would be a constant, not passed in from a parameter.

Comment: BTW, if performance at all matters, Casimir's answer is going to be faster than any other given by an order of magnitude, since it doesn't involve any `fork()` or `exec()` calls. `$(...)`, or its backtick-based equivalent, has a quite nontrivial performance penalty (if you're calling anything frequently enough for it to add up); likewise for pipelines and such.

Comment: Evaluating `cp $1 ~/dotfiles/` is going to do Very Very Bad Things if you have a file created with `touch $'evil-$(rm -rf $HOME)\'$(rm -rf $HOME)\''` you want to copy this way (the second copy inside the literal single quotes being to work around naive attempts at escaping with literal quotes in the format string). Why would you have the `fp` function emit code on its output, rather than having it just run `cp "dir5/dir6/${1#*/*/}" ~/dotfiles/` directly?

Comment: @Charles Duffy, what do you suggest I change it to instead?

Comment: @DanHerman, ...I already gave that suggestion. Have the function directly run the copy itself, not print code for the copy on its output. But if you **must** have it print code, then use `printf %q` to generate your variable content in an `eval`-safe manner. `fp() { printf 'cp %q ~/dotfiles/\n' "dir5/dir6/${1#*/*/}"; }`

Comment: The problem with "works for me" in bash is that things are full of corner cases. One former employer had literally multiple TB of backups of billing data (well, access logs used for billing) destroyed because someone didn't quote correctly in a shell script, and a tool generating filenames that shell script operated on had a buffer overflow and dumped a bunch of garbage (including a whitespace-surrounded `*`) into the name. If you decide that something's OK just because it works in the common case, without considering the corner cases, it's possible to get into a world of pain.

Comment: Re: update #2, this is an improvement, but still buggy -- quotes are important. Run it through http://shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a parameter expansion:

```
function fp {
    echo "dir5/dir6/${1#*/*/}"
}
```

Comment: It I were the op, this would have been my accepted answer :) The most elegant way of doing it.

Comment: @sjsam: thanks, but other answers are perfectly valuable too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a command substitution (`$(...)`) and then send it as an argument to `printf`. Also remember quotes around variable substitutions: `echo "$1"`

```
fp() {
  printf "dir5/dir6/%s\n" "$(printf "%s\n" "$1" | cut -d'/' -f4-)"
}
```

I changed the `function fp {` to the POSIX function definition `fp() {`

Answer (score 1):

```
function fp {
  printf "%s%s" "/dev5/dir6/" "$(echo "$1" | cut -d'/' -f4-)"
}
```

would do it. You could also do :

```
function fp {
  printf "%s%s" "$2" "$(echo "$1" | cut -d'/' -f4-)"
}
```

where `$2` is the path to append:

Call the function like

```
fp "dir1/dir2/dir3/file" "/dir5/dir6/"
```

Comment: @sjsam, even as-edited, I still don't see quotes around the `$1` in the `echo $1`s.

Comment: ...ahh, better now. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : I posted without a shellcheck in an urgency ;)

Comment: @DanHerman : Please see the edits which are important here. I see that this a dirty way of doing it. ;) [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37326938/1620779) would have been my preferred answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation can be as easy as putting the different parts next to each other. The path end you already produce can be put in a subshell (`$(...)`, or formerly `...`), which can itself be included in a double-quoted string so it will be expanded into its output :

```
function fp {
    echo "/dir5/dir6/$(echo "$1" | cut -d'/' -f4-)"
}
```

That being said, Casimir's answer's parameter expansion will be more efficient, and `printf` based solutions will me more portable (as well as arguably more readable).

Comment: `echo` is built-in, just as `printf` is, so they're equially efficient; the reasons to prefer printf are mostly built around portability, as the POSIX spec for `echo` leaves much of its behavior implementation-defined (including its handling of any string containing backslashes). See the APPLICATION USAGE section of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html

Comment: ...and if portability is a goal, changing `function fp {` to `fp() {` would do a great deal of good.

Comment: ...the big efficiency gains in, say, Casimir's answer come from replacing the command substitution with a parameter expansion.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback ! I've edited my answer to point out how all the other answers are better and why, I'll leave mine to illustrate that string concatenation is as easy as putting the substrings next to each other :)